# HTML Select: Eliminating browser Delay on keypress-to-change?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-select

Consider the following HTML:

```
<select>
    <option>Aardvark</option>
    <option>Buffalo</option>
    <option>Camel</option>
    <option>X-ray Fish</option>
    <option>Yak</option>
    <option>Zebra</option>
</select>
```

In most browsers, when the select element has focus, pressing a key will change the selected value to the next option that begins with the character typed. For instance, pressing 'B' on the keyboard while the `<select>` element above has focus changes the selected value to "Buffalo". Pressing 'Z' after that will change the value to "Zebra".

But I just discovered that, at least in Firefox 6 and Safari 5 on my PC, there is a delay before I can press-to-select the next value. In the specific example above, if I press "B" and then press "Z" less than a second later, nothing appears to happen.

However, in further testing (with jQuery) I discovered that the Javascript events 'keydown', 'keyup', and 'keypress' ARE all fired as you'd expect, no matter how rapidly you press the keys. The browsers themselves just don't switch the selected option until a certain period of time has passed.

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: The browser probably searches for a value starting for "BZ" (and fails) instead of jumping to the value starting with "Z". I guess you could override the key events and find the value yourself, but that's not much of a solution.

Comment: The way it works in browsers is that it searches for what you type. If you type bz, it searches for something starting bz. This is helpful for e.g. entering your birth year in those thrice-damned dropdown boxes, so you can just type 1984 or whatever. If you pause for a moment, the browser 'forgets' what you typed and you'll start a new 'search' when you type again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it by interrupting the keyevent and placing a `preventDefault()` at the top of the function. I use the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to break the delay and submit what I've typed already.

```
if (eventinfo.keyCode == 13) {
    eventinfo.preventDefault();
    var search = document.getElementById("searchtag");
    var value = search.value;
    mainPage.searchAdd(value).done(
        function () {
           search.value = "";
           search.focus();
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Congrats, you now get Best Answer. And only 5 years late. :)

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be possible with cloning. It's a really dirty hack but works just fine in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/v6qy8/2/.

```
$('select').keyup(function() {
    var newSelect = $(this).clone(true).val($(this).val());
    $(this).replaceWith(newSelect);
    newSelect.focus();
});
```

Comment: Closest to an actual solution.