# Extending the search reset time in an HTML select box

Tags: html

This question is slightly related to the following thread, except that I have the exact opposite problem:

[HTML Select: Eliminating browser Delay on keypress-to-change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434675/html-select-eliminating-browser-delay-on-keypress-to-change)

When running select boxes, there is a length of time specified during which if you press another key it will extend the search to include that letter. For instance, if I press B, it will search for options starting with "B". If I hit R within about a half second, it will search for options starting with "br"; however, if I wait too long it will begin a new search for options starting with "r".

My problem is that I have a user who needs a longer delay. She is a rather important user and we have to keep her needs satisfied. One frustration she has voiced numerous times is that the "search in the drop-down menu keeps starting over if she doesn't type fast enough". The simplest solution to me seems to be to increase the length of time of the delay so that the search doesn't restart for, say, 2 or 3 seconds after the last character was typed. I haven't been able to figure out how to do this, however, and I was hoping someone here good point me in the direction of a good fix. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I doubt it's possible in HTML or Javascript, because most (all?) browsers don't expose such fine detail of control behavior to any API you can get to that way.

Comment: What you *could* do would be to replace the select box with a text input and a `div` pretending to be a dropdown, and use the text in the input field to narrow the range of options available in the `div`; [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228628/jquery-select-simulation-with-input-and-div) might be a place to start. It'd take considerable effort to produce the desired result, but it sounds like the user is sufficiently important to justify the effort, and a side benefit is that you'll have much more ability to further fine-tune the control's behavior to suit her needs.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Is it possible to select your comment as an answer so you get the credit for it?