# Reset the Type-A-Value feature in HTML select elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface, drop-down-menu

We have many values in an HTML `<select>` element that we want the user to be able to type through quickly, pressing Enter to accept each one.

If the user types too quickly, though, then the selected value does not change. I don't know why, but I suspect this is because a select element requires the user to pause before the Type-a-value feature resets and they can start typing a new value, and pressing Enter doesn't reset it.

[Here's a jsFiddle that illustrates my problem:](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2aQb/)

**HTML**

```
<select>
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
    <option>d</option>
    <option>e</option>
</select>

<ol>
</ol>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('select').on('keydown',function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) { // Enter
        $('ol').append('<li>' + $('select').val() + '</li>');
    }
});
```

If you're fast enough, you'll fill up the `<ol>` with the same value no matter what you type. What can be changed so that a fast user gets only the values they typed?

Comment: Consider using something like [jQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) instead for long lists. Select dropdowns are well-suited only to short lists.

Comment: I'd assume this is a flaw with (or intended behavior of) the native select box implementation. It doesn't seem to change *as soon* as the keydown event happens, so your handler is firing before it changes to match whatever key the user clicked. My guess, though. You can check it by logging the value of the select.You should consider manually setting the value of the select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not seem like an optimal solution, but you could try to implement what **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434675/html-select-eliminating-browser-delay-on-keypress-to-change)** states regarding cloning and replacing the original object:

```
$('select').on('keydown',function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) { // Enter
        $('ol').append('<li>' + this.value + '</li>');
        var newSelect = $(this).clone(true).val(this.value);
        $(this).replaceWith(newSelect);
        newSelect.focus();
    }
});
```

At least it works for me on Chrome 26...

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/MEZ5Y/)**

Comment: Good contribution, but it certainly feels like a hack. If I'm referencing my select with `$('select')` all the time then there's no problem. If I'm using `var select = $('select'); select.on('keydown'...` then clone/replace starts breaking things.

Comment: Then again, `select = newSelect;` should fix the majority of those problems. I think I like it.

Comment: Since we're using Knockout.JS, we implemented this basic idea using a `with` binding on a variable that we set to `false`, then back to `true` inside a `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to fix it if you add

```
$('select').blur().focus();
```

after processing each enter key press.

Comment: Sorry, that worked for firefox.  IE seems to remember previously typed characters even if you .remove() and re-add the select box.